# Azure Container/Kubernetes Service - Network interface and IPs are not deleted

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service, azure-aks

Azure Container/Kubernetes Service - Virtual Network : 
IPs and network interface are not deleted/cleaned after pods deletion.

No more available address in the subnet that kubernetes use after a few deployments.

Is there a way to clean those network interface?

Comment: what's the Kubernetes version? This used to be a problem in acs-engine/azure-cni but it should be long fixed in AKS ([reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-container-networking/issues/76))

Comment: Shouldn't you delete the deployment of the pods? Maybe I do not really understand it.

Comment: @alev: the kubernetes version is 1.11.13

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT This problem occurs when I delete a namespace or a specific deployment, AKS does not remove the network interfaces related to the namespace or the deployments/pods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RESOLVED:
By default, AKS is reserving 31 ips for each node in the cluster so my problem was not that the IPs were not released but just that a lot of IPs were reserved :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try and see if you can:

- [Remove IP addresses](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface-addresses.md#remove-ip-addresses),
- [Delete a network interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface#delete-a-network-interface) and/or
- [find and delete unattached network interface cards (NICs) for Azure VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/find-unattached-nics)

Comment: @VonC I used the script from script to find and delete unattached network interface but the problem is that those network interfaces are still connected to the VMs that belongs to the AKS cluster. AKS should be the one freeing the network interfaces after a deletion happen in the cluster...

Comment: @Ben Strange. May be this is an ownership issue? (as in https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/427#issuecomment-397368508)